# Reference cell.offset from another sheet

Tags: excel, vba, offset

I just started using VBA so Im stuck.

I am having it check if there is a unit number, check if there is a checkmark present, and if the value is less than 8.  Then returning the value.  This is what I have so far and it works great, but I need to change it to pull the value from another sheet. (Rather than a hidden (-8 offset) column on the active sheet)

'Make sure no blank unit numbers

```
    If cell.Offset(0, -7).Value <> "" Then
    
        If cell.Offset(0, -2).Value = ChrW(&H2713) And cell.Offset(0, -8).Value < 8 Then
            cell.Value = cell.Offset(0, -8).Value
        End If
```

There's more but this is the part I need to change.   I need the "cell.offset(0, -8).value <8" to instead reference a cell on another sheet (say...Sheet5 A13 for example) and to to return that value if true in the active cell (offset 0,0).

BUT....this code repeats through a range of cells on the active sheet!  It starts at I47 and goes through I119, checking for true in every row and returning the corresponding value.

So I am at a loss.  Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to a cell in any sheet using `Worksheets("sheet name").cells(...` syntax.

There are other ways like declaring a variable to hold a reference to that sheet and using it in several places, or addressing the other sheet by its number, etc, but start with this, and research other ways afterwards

Answer (score -1):

I think you want this ...

```
If cell.Offset(0, -7).Value <> "" Then
    If cell.Offset(0, -2).Value = ChrW(&H2713) And ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Other Worksheet Name").Range(cell.Offset(0, -8).Address).Value < 8 Then
        cell.Value = cell.Offset(0, -8).Value
    End If
End If
```

Use the address of the current cell with offset on the other sheet.